# How to get rid of the warning .ts file is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I Just updated angular to latest `9.0.0-next.4`. I am not using routing but suddenly after updating I keep seeing this warning. How Do I remove this warning

> WARNING in `src/war/angular/src/app/app-routing.module.ts` is part of
>   the TypeScript compilation but it's unused. Add only entry points to
>   the 'files' or 'include' properties in your tsconfig.

**package.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^9.0.0-next.4",
"@angular/cdk": "^8.1.4",
"@angular/common": "^9.0.0-next.4",
"@angular/compiler": "^9.0.0-next.4",
"@angular/core": "^9.0.0-next.4",
"@angular/forms": "^9.0.0-next.4",
"@angular/material": "^8.1.4",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^9.0.0-next.4",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.0.0-next.4",
"@angular/router": "^9.0.0-next.4",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.1.0",
"bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"moment": "^2.24.0",
"ng-image-slider": "^2.0.1",
"panzoom": "^8.1.2",
"rxjs": "~6.5.2",
"tslib": "^1.9.0",
"zone.js": "^0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.0.0-next.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.0.0-next.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "^5.15.0",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3"
  }
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
    {
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: In my case I had classes that I used as interface, but no usages of those classes were found in the code. so I deleted them all.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

It turned out that you need to remove this line from "include"
`"src/**/*.ts"` from `tsconfig.app.json` and only keep entry points in files (main.ts and polyfills.ts)

Comment: It seems adding those files in exclude part of `tsconfig.app.json` solves the issue

Comment: I didn't even have `"include" "src/**/*.ts"` in my `tsconfig.app.json` and I still get the warning messages.

Comment: you have it in tsconfig.json may be? It gets inherited

Comment: I do not have an include anywhere in my tsconfig's. I do have some excludes already. But I get 29 of these warnings. If I add in the include for main and polyfills I still get 3.  I can't seem to exclude those three with any combination of paths.

Comment: I fixed this by updating angular-cli with `npm i @angular/cli@latest`

Comment: This results in `Cannot find name 'describe'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner?`, which can be cured by reversing the changes made in this answer.

Comment: nothing workds angular-cli is on latest version, no includes on tsconfig. any solution so far?

Comment: any idea why I didn't get this for Angular 9 and got swamped with Angular 10 with all these messages?

Comment: Make sure and check the base `tsconfig.json` file too, if `tsconfig.app.json` extends it, or another file.

Comment: I have to set the include for autocompletion in vscode. Is there a way to keep this and suppress the warnings?

Answer (score 61):

I could get it working by defining the `files` property in `tsconfig.app.json`. These files are relative to the `tsconfig.app.json` file.

```
"files": [
    "main.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ]
```

Comment: In my case I did not have a specific files array entry in my tsconfig.app.json, and I would receive the error message for just about every new .ts file I added to the project. Explicitly adding the 'files' array with the 2 entry files above, cleared the warnings.

Answer (score 30):

I had seen these messages complaining about environment.*.ts files which are actually mentioned in angular.json for different builds, after upgrading from Angular 8 to Angular 9 including CLI local and global. However, I did not run `ng update` which might update tsconfig.json with the following, instead I updated tsconfig.json manually.

```js
    "files": [
        "src/main.ts",
        "src/polyfills.ts"
    ],
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.d.ts"
    ]
```

Then the warnings disappear.

**Update 2020-05-27 with Angular 9.1.x in Visual Studio Professional 2019**

The little block above is not needed anymore. Otherwise, it will cause the spec test codes complaining "module not found" against modules which are actually there since `ng test` is building and running just fine, and the build and the running of the ng app are OK. Apparently somethings in NG had changed between 9 and 9.1.

Here's my working tsconfig.json now:

```js
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "module": "es2020",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "lib": [
            "es2018",
            "dom"
        ],
        "skipLibCheck": true
    }
}
```

**remarks:**

I target Google Chrome and Safari only, so if you want to target other browsers, you may need to adjust accordingly.

Comment: I changed the value for **include** in my tsconfig.app.json from:
["./**/*.ts"]
to
    ["./**/*.d.ts"]

That removed the warning for me.

Comment: For me not. I removed the `.ts` entry (only kept `.d.ts`). Fewer warnings now. But not entirely removed. I checked any tsconfig.

Answer (score 22):

#### Are you using @angular-builders/custom-webpack?

I was getting bombarded with these messages in Angular 10 having never seen them before. Changing `includes` made no difference.

Then I found https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/36211.

This is essentially the same error as raised in this question but for `ngtypecheck.ts` files (whatever they are *exactly* i'm not sure!)

> WARNING in /home/circleci/ng/aio/src/main.ngtypecheck.ts is part of
> the TypeScript compilation but it's unused. Add only entry points to
> the 'files' or 'include' properties in your tsconfig.

It looks like for me it's actually to do with `@angular-builders/custom-webpack`.

https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/issues/781
where an issue was only just opened. Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/62573294/16940 for pointing this out.

Updating to the v10.0.1 fixed it for me, but see the above issue for the latest.

```
"@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "10.0.1"    // as of today
```

Comment: Same here using @angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^9.2.0 tried every solution out there nothing seems to stop WARNING's

Comment: @ramon22 switching to 10.0.0-beta0 worked for me. Any remaining errors were to do with CommonJS packages.

Comment: You may also need to install or link webpack if you receive **Cannot find module webpack**

Comment: (About Sielu's comment) My technique is to install webpack (so it's specified explicitly in `devDependencies`), and add the same entry to `resolutions` to avoid potentially having multiple version of webpack installed (@angular-devkit#build-angular has webpack in its peer deps), since that could also cause various problems. To check if you have multiple versions of webpack installed, type `yarn why webpack` (and if you're working with npm, do yourself a favor and stop ;)).

Comment: As of now, you can do `"@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^10.0.1"`

Comment: If you got `Cannot find module webpack`, delete your package-lock.json and run `npm i` again. It should fix the problem. I am upgrading my pet project to Angular 10 https://github.com/trungk18/jira-clone-angular

Answer (score 21):

This may seem obvious, BUT you will see this warning for any file that you add but is not yet referenced/imported into another file. This will become obvious when you attempt to edit one of the files subject to the warning, and Ivy does not automatically recompile after editing the file. Once you import the module into a dependent file and start using it, the warnings go away.

The answers above may be relevant to some, but what I just described in this post was the root cause of my warnings. Note, I do not have an include or files array in my tsconfig.json or tsconfig.app.json and the warnings went away as soon as I actually referenced the files elsewhere in my project.

Comment: this actually answers the question and should be the marked answer - as the poster says "I am not using routing" and it is complaining that the routing file is unused... so either use it or delete it and the warning will go away

Comment: I tried all the other answers first but in the end this answer worked for me and it was the most simplist one. I actually had a few modules and I just had to add it to one of them for the error to disappear.

Answer (score 20):

Updated to Angular 9 today and got warnings.
My solution was add this "files" array without the "src" in the path. Just added:

```
 "files": [
    "main.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
```

My full tsconfig.app.json file is:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": ["node"]
  },
  "files": [
    "main.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: get file " .../main.ts", not found error with angular 10

Comment: my main.ts file path its: "src\main.ts", check if yours is the same. Anyway: I'm with Angular 9 yet.

Answer (score 9):

**02-08-2020**

Ionic 5+ Angular 9+ App.

**Note:** see the `include` section.

`tsconfig.app.json`

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: can you add more explination? I have coppied this & still got an error

Comment: @Evan This is for Angular 9. What is your version here?

Answer (score 5):

Just add the zone-flags.ts as well and remove any includes.

```
 "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts",
    "src/zone-flags.ts"
  ]
```

Comment: Worked for me in Angular 10.0.1.

Answer (score 5):

**tsconfig.app.json**

```
 "exclude": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
  ]
```

*This snippet solves the issue.*

Answer (score 4):

I began to see the warnings in `Angular 10` which is a little surprising based on the fact it was a new app created using the CLI out of the box and I got the messages when doing a prod build for `test.ts` and `enviornments.prod.ts`. I'd think these files would be excluded by default, but they are not and that's odd.

The deal is these files are *not* needed for TypeScript transpolation; they don't need `.js` versions of the files to be bundled and sent to the browser. The `test.ts` and `environments.prod.ts` files are a means to an end for build time requirements in Angular. Therefore they can be added to the `exclude` section in `tsconfig.app.json` or applicable TypeScript configuration file in your app like below:

```
  "exclude": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
  ]
```

Once these are added as above, the warning will not show anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Try to delete the folder `node_modules/.cli-ngcc` which includes the Angular CLI cache files.

Answer (score 2):

after try out the before solutions proposals , it worked for me

update in your package.json

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.3"
```

can you see here all versions.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-devkit/build-angular?activeTab=versions

check which version work with you current version from angular/core

for angular 10 work with version **0.1000.3** of **@angular-devkit/build-angular**

Comment: the solution worked for me, however better to do this: based on the link you provided:   npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party.

I got this error

```
src/environments/environment.prod.ts is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused.
Add only entry points to the 'files' or 'include' properties in your tsconfig
```

To fix it I need to add include config to my tsconfig.app.json

```
"files": ["src/main.ts", "src/polyfills.ts"],
"include": ["src/**/*.d.ts"],
```

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading to Angular 10 I got the same warnings. Running `npm i` reported version mismatches for some dev dependencies. After upgrading these (`npm i <package>@latest`), and updating nodejs to version 12 (was version 10), the warnings were gone.

In my case, these were the packages that had to be updated:

- `@angular-devkit/build-angular`
- `codelyzer`

Comment: just this worked for me: ng update @angular-devkit/build-angular

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the classes reported by the warning were really used. However, the problem was that when importing them, they had the extension ".js".

So, this line was causing the error "WARNING in src\app\user.service.ts is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused":

```
import { UserService } from './user.service.js';
```

And I could fixed it by removing ".js" extension:

```
import { UserService } from './user.service';
```

Answer (score 1):

My team has been banging our head against this same symptom for months, and I finally figured out that our `tsconfig.worker.json` was too inclusive. In our case hundreds of "part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused" messages were showing-- it seemed like every ts file in the app was listed, some multiple times.

The way it was:

```
"include": [
  "src/**/*.worker.ts"
]
```

What stopped the defective behavior:

```
"files": [ ]   # no include or exclude block
```

I *think* what was happening is that our standard tsconfig.app.json's `files` object was sufficient. From just those entry points (main.ts & polyfills.ts), the TS compiler was able to find references to all our *.worker.ts files and transpile them. Somehow the tsconfig.webworker.ts configuration was telling the compiler to look twice at all *.webworker.ts files. I'm not quite sure why that explodes into so many warnings; perhaps our webworker files (we have about 20) are  unnecessarily importing a bunch of things they don't use.

Anyway, with this tweak, I got rid of the numerous warnings, and our compilation time cut in half. Phew!

Comment: I would add a general comment about tsconfig files. Be conservative about what you put in the `files` and `includes` objects. There's a mental tendency to think "Oh, I need to reference all my files here!" but this is not true. As an experiment, strip out everything in `include` and `files` blocks, and add back only what you need to make the build succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many things to solve this problem, and in the end I was able to solve it.

my problem was updating an app that was found in angular 8.1 to angular 9.x, but the app also used Ionic

you should only have `aot: true` inside `angular.json`

in src / polyfills.ts to import './zone-flags.ts'; remove .ts

https://medium.com/@grantbrits/upgrade-ionic-4-to-ionic-5-angular-76514079fb2a[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvZHc.png)

Comment: https://medium.com/@grantbrits/upgrade-ionic-4-to-ionic-5-angular-76514079fb2a

Comment: Just add ./zone-flags.ts to the files section in your tsconfig.app.json.

Do NOT modify the polyfills.ts

Answer (score 0):

Check your main `tsconfig.app.json` file.

[image]

and see whether you have following content inside,

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Most likely, the lines to blame were this.

> Add only entry points to the `files` or `include` properties in your tsconfig.

So, remove these lines should you have on your `tsconfig.app.json`. That's what the error is about :)

```
"exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
```

I hope this will help someone.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue after updating angular 9 app to angular 10. Updating angular-devkit solved it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was easier to exclude the non used file :

```
"exclude": ["test.ts", "**/*.spec.ts","environments/environment.*.ts"]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, my tsconfig.json was missing the exclude with spec files in it. This is the snippet of my tsconfig file which fixed the issue.

```
"exclude": [
"**/*.spec.ts",
"./node_modules/*"
],
 "files": [
"src/main.ts",
"src/polyfills.ts"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the problem is that on run time the compiler checks whether those files are imported or used somewhere and if they are not it throws warnings...
So if the warnings are connected with environment.ts files you can exclude the environment files in tsconfig.app.json as shown above in the comments but if there are warnings about some components which are not imported anywhere, you must check those components and see why they are not used, and if you do not need them just remove them.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem. The problem I had was that my angular.json was targeting the wrong tsConfig file. It was targeting tsconfig.json, rather than tsconfig.app.json.

Fix in angular.json:

```
"build": {
    "options": {
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    }
}
```

tsconfig.app.json extends tsconfig.json, and included the 'files' and 'include' arrays to get rid of the issue.

Answer (score -5):

For me, the problem was that I was using:

```
loadChildren: () => import('./components/admin/_admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule)
```

in my routes.ts file but wasn't importing module. So if I just put

```
import { AdminModule } from './components/admin/_admin.module';
```

it solves it.

Comment: This is a lazy loaded module, and there doesn't seem to be a reason why you would want to import it, to kill the lazyloadedness.