# How to exclude unused TS files in Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript

I updated from Angular 7 to Angular 9 and now getting a bunch of errors similar to this one.

> WARNING in
>   C:\Users\DEV-SYS\Documents\GitHub\Angular-7\src\environments\environment.prod.ts
>   is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused. Add only entry
>   points to the 'files' or 'include' properties in your tsconfig.

One way to get rid of them would be to delete the file but since i might need the one or other later, how can i tell the system not to try to compile ? I tried adding the below to my tsconfig.app.json with not much luck.

```
  "exclude": [
        "test.ts",
        "**/*.spec.ts",
        "environment.prod.ts"
    ]
```

What am i missing here ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57729518/how-to-get-rid-of-the-warning-ts-file-is-part-of-the-typescript-compilation-but

Answer (score -1):

As your environment.prod.ts is inside nested folders, you will have to give something like this.

```
 "exclude": [
        "test.ts",
        "**/*.spec.ts",
        "./src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
    ]
```

The path you have give form excluding environment.prod.ts file is wrong.

Comment: Tried adding the path like your sample but still complains with same warning

Comment: What about the test.ts file? Where is it placed in the folder structure?

Comment: src\test.ts is the location of the file test.ts