# Upgrading To Angular 9

Tags: angular

I updated my Angular project from V8 to V9. After upgrading successfully and when I run the project it gave me the following warnings:
*/src/main.ngtypecheck.ts is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused.
Add only entry points to the 'files' or 'include' properties in your tsconfig.

I followed as answer which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57729518/how-to-get-rid-of-the-warning-ts-file-is-part-of-the-typescript-compilation-but).
But I still get the warnings. Here is my tsconfig.app.ts

```
{
"extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "include": [
    "main.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ]
}
```

If someone found the solution, please share.

Comment: what about your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: {
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}