# Angular15 - WARNING with TypeScript compilation

Tags: typescript, compilation, angular15

I've updated my Angular Version from 14 to 15. Now when starting the application I'm getting this warnings. Not only one but 22 of those, for different files.

> WARNING in /Users/.../src/environments/environment.prod.ts is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused. Add only entry points to the 'files' or 'include' properties in your tsconfig.

My current tsconfig.app.json is this:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableResourceInlining": true,
    "generateCodeForLibraries": true,
    "compilationMode": "partial"
  },
  "angularOptions": {
    "annotationsAs": "decorators"
  }
}
```

I've tried all changes of files, include, exclude like described

[here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17066)

and

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57729518/how-to-get-rid-of-the-warning-ts-file-is-part-of-the-typescript-compilation-but)

But nothing helped. Most of the answers are regarding Angular 9 or 10. Maybe for Angular 15 its a different behavior.

Does anyone, using Angular 15 have seen this warnings and now the solution? I would be so thankful!